# Small Python math library

Tags: python, mathematics, library

I have been writing a math library with more options than the standard builtin one, partially to make my life easier in the future, and partially just for practice.
Here is what I have so far in the main file (master/xtrmth/xm.py):

```py
import typing as tp
import decimal as dc

_meganum = tp.Union[int, float, dc.Decimal, tp.SupportsInt, tp.SupportsFloat]
_num = tp.Union[int, float, dc.Decimal]
_micronum = tp.Union[int, float]
_decnum = tp.Union[float, dc.Decimal]

def _total_round(value: _num, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False) -> _num:
    """Rounds 'value' to the nearest 'precision' digits."""
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value
    elif precision < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot cast a negative integer onto \'xm._total_round(precision)\'')
    elif decimal is True:
        if isinstance(value, dc.Decimal):
            return round(value, precision)
        elif not isinstance(value, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
            raise TypeError('Cannot cannot cast \'float\' onto \'xm._total_round(value)\' \
with opperand \'decimal\' as \'True\'.')
    elif decimal is False:
        if isinstance(value, float):
            return round(value, precision)
        elif not isinstance(value, float):
            raise TypeError('Cannot cast \'decimal\' onto \'xm._total_round(value)\' \
with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'.')
    
def summation(count: int, bottom_var: str, expression: str, precision: int = 10, \
decimal: bool = False) -> _num:
    '''Summation function. Example: 'summation(4, 'z=1', 'z+1')' would return 14.'''
    
    if precision < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot cast a negative integer onto \'xm.summation(precision)\'')
    var, value = bottom_var.split('=')
    var = var.strip()
    
    if decimal is True:
        value = dc.Decimal(eval(value))
    else:
        value = int(eval(value))

    res = 0
    for i in range(value, count+1):
        res += eval(expression.replace(var, str(i)))

    if decimal is True:
        return _total_round(value=res, precision=precision, decimal=True)
    return _total_round(res, precision=precision, decimal=False)

def sq(value: _num, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False, _print_unround: bool = False) -> _micronum:
    '''Returns 'value' raised to the 2nd power, with 'precision' decimal points.'''
    if isinstance(value, float) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cannot cast \'float\' onto \'xm.cb\' \
with opperand \'decimal\' as \'True\'.')
    elif isinstance(value, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cannot cast \'decimal\' onto \'xm.cb\' \
with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'.')
    elif isinstance(value, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        if _print_unround is True:
            print(value*value)
        return _total_round(value*value, precision, decimal=True)
    if _print_unround is True:
        print(value*value)
    return _total_round(value*value, precision, decimal=False)

def sqrt(value: _meganum, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False, _print_unround: bool = False) -> _num:
    if decimal is True:
        x = dc.Decimal(value)
        y = dc.Decimal(1)
        e = dc.Decimal(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
    else:
        x = value
        y = 1
        e = 0.0000000000000000000000001
    
    while x - y > e:
        x = (x + y)/2
        y = value / x

    if _print_unround is True:
        print(x)

    return(_total_round(x, precision, decimal=decimal))

def cb(value: _meganum, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False, _print_unround: bool = False) -> _num:
    '''Returns 'value' raised to the 2nd power, with '''
    if isinstance(value, float) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cannot cast \'float\' onto \'xm.cb\' \
with opperand \'decimal\' as \'True\'.')
    elif isinstance(value, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cannot cast \'decimal\' onto \'xm.cb\' \
with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'.')
    elif isinstance(value, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        if _print_unround is True:
            print(value*value*value)
        return _total_round(value*value*value, precision, decimal=True)
    if _print_unround is True:
        print(value*value*value)
    return _total_round(value*value*value, precision, decimal=False)

def cbrt(value, _print_unround: bool = False) -> _num:
    x = value**(1/3)

    if _print_unround is True:
        print(x)

    if type(x) is float:
        if round(x, 10) == int(round(x, 10)): return int(round(x, 10))
        return round(x, 10)
    return x

def xpn(base: _meganum, exponent: _meganum, decimal: bool = False, precision: int = 10, _print_debug: bool = False) \
-> _num:
    '''Raises 'base' to the power of 'exponent'.'''
    
    if not isinstance(base, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError(f'Cannot cast \'{type(base).__name__()}\' onto \'xm.xpn(base)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'True\'')
    elif isinstance(base, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cast \'decimal.Decimal\' onto \'xm.xpn(base)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
        
    out = 1
    
    if isinstance(exponent, int):
        if _print_debug is True:
            print('exponent is int')
        for i in range(exponent):
            if _print_debug is True:
                print(out)
            out *= base
        return _total_round(out, precision=precision, decimal=decimal)
    else:
        # will update with my own algorithim in a later update
        return _total_round(base**exponent, precision=precision, decimal=decimal)

def rt(base: _meganum, root: _meganum, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False, _print_debug: bool = False) -> _num:
    '''Takes the 'root' root of 'base' '''

    if isinstance(base, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cast \'decimal.Decimal\' onto \'xm.rd(base)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
    elif not isinstance(base, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError(f'Cannot cast \'{type(base).__name__}\' onto \'xm.rd(base)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
    elif isinstance(root, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cast \'decimal.Decimal\' onto \'xm.rd(root)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
    elif not isinstance(root, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError(f'Cannot cast \'{type(root).__name__}\' onto \'xm.rd(root)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'True\'')
    
    if decimal is True:
        return xpn(base = base, exponent = (dc.Decimal(1) / root), decimal = True, precision = precision, _print_debug = _print_debug)
    return xpn(base = base, exponent = (1 / root), decimal = False, precision = precision, _print_debug = _print_debug)
```

Is there anything I should change?

Github page: [Github](https://github.com/CATboardBETA/xtrmth)
PyPI page: [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/xtrmth/)

Comment: `cb(…) -> _num:
    '''Returns 'value' raised to the 2nd power, with '''` Again?

Comment: @greybeard That was a mistype in the docstring.

Comment: (I'd call it a C&PE: *Copy&Paste Error*. In the "original code", probably, rather than in transferring to SE. Keep in mind a) posting on SE puts contents under a Creative Commons licence b) docstrings are available during execution via introspection.)

Comment: @greybeard No, I simply made a mistype. It's not that rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General

`import typing as tp` => `from typing import Union` reduces acronyms reader needs to remmber

Backslashes are scary. Adding parentheses or in this case trusting the existing ones will  be easier to read.

```
def summation(count: int, bottom_var: str, expression: str, precision: int = 10, \
decimal: bool = False) -> _num:
```

Again, backslashes are scary.

```
raise ValueError('Cannot cast a negative integer onto \'xm.summation(precision)\'')
# could be
raise ValueError("Cannot cast a negative integer onto 'xm.summation(precision)'")
```

There are a lot of underscores here. Exposing the important functions in an separate file would reduce the need to hide everything.

## Functions

Each of your functions are written in a pretty similar style, so I'll just look at one of them.

```
def rt(base: _meganum, root: _meganum, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False, _print_debug: bool = False) -> _num:
    '''Takes the 'root' root of 'base' '''

    if isinstance(base, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cast \'decimal.Decimal\' onto \'xm.rd(base)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
    elif not isinstance(base, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError(f'Cannot cast \'{type(base).__name__}\' onto \'xm.rd(base)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
    elif isinstance(root, dc.Decimal) and decimal is False:
        raise TypeError('Cannot cast \'decimal.Decimal\' onto \'xm.rd(root)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'False\'')
    elif not isinstance(root, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
        raise TypeError(f'Cannot cast \'{type(root).__name__}\' onto \'xm.rd(root)\' with opperand \'decimal\' as \'True\'')
    
    if decimal is True:
        return xpn(base = base, exponent = (dc.Decimal(1) / root), decimal = True, precision = precision, _print_debug = _print_debug)
    return xpn(base = base, exponent = (1 / root), decimal = False, precision = precision, _print_debug = _print_debug)
```

- You can afford more than 2 characters for a function name.
- The `Decimal` type as an edge case clutters up both your usage and your library code.
- The conditional statements can be removed by taking advantage of features these types already have

```
def nth_root(base: _meganum, n: _meganum, precision: int = 10) -> _num:
    '''Takes the nth root of 'base' '''
    # works for Decimals, ints, floats, whatever
    exponent = n ** -1
    return xpn(base=base, exponent=exponent, precision=precision)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here?

> ```
> elif decimal is True:
>     ⋮
> elif decimal is False:
> ```

Firstly, especially since we annotated that `decimal` is boolean, we should just be testing its truthiness; secondly, at the `elif` we already know that `decimal` isn't true.  So, simply write

> ```
> elif decimal:
>     ⋮
> else:
> ```

Applying this simple change throughout already cuts a lot of unnecessary verbiage and improves the readability.

The immediately preceding code shows we shouldn't be in `elif` anyway

> ```
> if isinstance(value, int):
>     return …
> elif precision < 0:
>     raise …
> elif decimal is True:
> ```

Since `return` and `raise` both exit the flow of control, we can reduce cognitive load thus:

```
if isinstance(value, int):
    return …
if precision < 0:
    raise …
if decimal:
```

Looking inside the `if decimal` case, we see:

> ```
>   elif decimal is True:
>         if isinstance(value, dc.Decimal):
>             return …
>         elif not isinstance(value, dc.Decimal) and decimal is True:
>             raise …
> ```

In last condition, we know that `decimal` is true and that `value` is not a `dc.Decimal`, so that one just becomes a plain `else` - and not needed because the previous clause returned:

```
  elif decimal:
        if not isinstance(value, dc.Decimal):
            raise …
        return …
```

Just simplifying the control flow in that one function makes it a lot simpler:

```
def _total_round(value: _num, precision: int = 10, decimal: bool = False) -> _num:
    """Rounds 'value' to the nearest 'precision' digits."""
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value
    if precision < 0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot cast a negative integer onto 'xm._total_round(precision)'")
    if decimal and not isinstance(value, dc.Decimal):
        raise TypeError("Cannot cannot cast 'float' onto 'xm._total_round(value)' \
with operand 'decimal' as 'True'.")
    if not decimal and not isinstance(value, float):
        raise TypeError("Cannot cast 'decimal' onto 'xm._total_round(value)' \
with operand 'decimal' as 'False'.")
    return round(value, precision)
```

---

Looking again from further away, I don't see any unit-tests at all.  What happened to them?

Comment: To most of this: understood, I will change (note though that `_total_round()` has already been greatly simplified since I made this post). To the unit tests: I usually just go into the REPL, import the file, and try out the functions.

Comment: A good regression suite is well worth cultivating, and in Python it's easy to include it under `if __name__ == '__main__'`.  Definitely consider writing some tests - and for your next project, they are even more valuable if you use them to write the code!

Comment: I just left the ugly wrapped strings as is, because I was focusing on the control flow. The other answer deals with that more effectively (Python isn't my main language, so I didn't want to over-step my competence!)

Comment: @TobySpeight Sorry didn't get pung. Oh, I thought you were the one to change the strings... I see now I was wrong. Sorry.